'coffeescript@1' is not in this registry
I use ionic 6 and angular 15 for my mobile application, now when I try to install cordova-sqlite-storage with command

ionic cordova plugin add cordova-sqlite-storage

I found this error:
enter image description here
this is code package.json:
    {
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "postinstall": "ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.10",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/device": "^6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/network": "6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/splash-screen": "6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/sqlite": "6.6.0",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/status-bar": "^6.7.0",
    "@capacitor/network": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/splash-screen": "^5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^5.0.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.7.5",
    "@ionic/cli": "^6.20.9",
    "@ionic/cordova-builders": "^11.0.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "4.0.0",
    "@okta/okta-auth-js": "7.5.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.200",
    "angular-ng-autocomplete": "^2.0.12",
    "angular-oauth2-oidc": "12.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.3.3",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "cordova": "^12.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.3",
    "cordova-res": "^0.15.4",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.36.0",
    "flickity": "3.0.0",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "^5.0.0",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "karma": "^6.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^2.0.1",
    "moment": "2.22.2",
    "popper.js": "1.12.6",
    "postcss-px2rem-exclude": "^0.0.6",
    "puppeteer": "^5.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.7",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.10",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.0.0",
    "@capacitor/assets": "^3.0.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "5.7.2",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^9.0.0",
    "@types/events": "^3.0.3",
    "@types/flickity": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.18.63",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.19.10",
    "coffeescript": "^1.12.7",
    "cordova-android": "^12.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "typescript": "~4.9.3"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {}
    },
    "platforms": []
  }
}

in devDependencies I add

"coffeescript": "^1.12.7",
and I delete package-lock.json and node_modules but also error

how to fix this error please.
